# How to make multiline TextInput textAlign to justify right? React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I need to show multiline texts in a TextInput, but I need to **justify them from the right**. 
I used `textAlign: 'justify',` for the component's style, but it has not been justified from right.

```
<TextInput multiline={true} 
                  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                  editable={this.props.editable} 
                  style={[{backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                            left: 10,
                            right: 10,
                            textAlign: 'justify',
                            textAlignVertical: 'top',
                            fontFamily: 'B Yekan',
                            fontSize: 12,
                            lineHeight: 17,
                            }, this.props.style]} >
    //My text is showing here
</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gravity="end", I just tried it and it seems to solve your problem.

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't work. My texts are right to left and with your solution, nothing is changed

Comment: Have you tried gravity="start", or "right" or "left"? layout_gravity may also work